# Python-Gstreamer from scratch: tcpclientsrc Not linked

Tags: python-2.7, gstreamer

Is there a Python-G-Streamer expert that can help med with my little script..?
As a newbie is not easy to figure out what went wrong here.

Setup: Stream from A: tcpserversink to B: tcpclientsrc
Caps are set at the serverside.
Issue: On B: When pipe is start to roll, stream get paused. Error: tcpclientsrc: not linked (-1)
I can make a pipe with gst-launch-1.0 that will run and I know that my stream are right, because if A: tcpserversink is not running i'll get the expectet error-message from gst, that say's connection refused. 
I suspect that is might be a lack of a pad for the tcpclientsrc.
My script is based on a player that was working, so I only try to change the source to tcpclientsrc. Also layout been change from Gtk-Hardcode, to be layout'et with Glade and that works to. Unfortunately the original script was using playbin and so not much about pad or something like that.
If anyone allready have a script that based on tcpclientsrc, I would be happy to take look at that, so I can correct my script.
I haven't found a single example using tcpserversink / tcpclientlink on the web. :-o

Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, platform

try:
  import gi
except:
  print("No GI")
try:
  gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
  from gi.repository import GObject,Gtk as Gtk
except:
  print("No Gtk")
try:
  gi.require_version ('Gst', '1.0')
  from gi.repository import Gst
except:
  print("No Gst")
try:
# Needed for window.get_xid(), xvimagesink.set_window_handle(), respectively:
  gi.require_version('GdkX11', '3.0')
  from gi.repository import GdkX11
except:
  print("No GdkX11 3.0")
try:
  gi.require_version('GstVideo', '1.0')
  from gi.repository import GstVideo
except:
  print("No GstVideo 1.0")
  sys.exit(1)


class GTK_Main(object):

def __init__(self):
    ## Create a window,
    self.gladefile = ("hello_Gstream_tcpclient_work.glade")
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
    self.builder.connect_signals(self)

    ## Create objects by name from Glade
    self.window = self.builder.get_object("window")
    self.movie_window = self.builder.get_object("movie_window")
    self.button1 = self.builder.get_object("button1")
    self.button2 = self.builder.get_object("button2")
    self.button3 = self.builder.get_object("button3")
    self.entry_host_1 = self.builder.get_object("entry_host_1")
    self.entry_host_2 = self.builder.get_object("entry_host_2")
    self.entry_host_3 = self.builder.get_object("entry_host_3")
    self.entry_port_1 = self.builder.get_object("entry_port_1")
    self.entry_port_2 = self.builder.get_object("entry_port_2")
    self.entry_port_3 = self.builder.get_object("entry_port_3")
    self.window.show_all()

    ## Create pipeline & connect bus
    self.player = Gst.Pipeline.new("player")
    bus = self.player.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.enable_sync_message_emission()
    bus.connect("message", self.on_message)
    bus.connect("sync-message::element", self.on_sync_message)

    ## Create tcpclientsr, gdpdepay, rtph264depay, h264parse, decodebin,
    ## videoconvert, autovideosink
    self.tcpclientsrc_1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("tcpclientsrc", "tcpclientsrc_1")
    self.gdpdepay_1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("gdpdepay", "gdpdepay_1")
    self.rtph264depay_1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtph264depay", "rtph264depay_1")
    self.h264parse_1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("h264parse", "h264parse_1")
    self.decodebin_1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("decodebin", "decodebin_1")
    self.videoconvert_1 = Gst.ElementFactory.make("videoconvert", "videoconvert_1")
    self.autovideosink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autovideosink", "autovideosink")

    ## Add elements to pibeline
    self.player.add(self.tcpclientsrc_1)
    self.player.add(self.gdpdepay_1)
    self.player.add(self.rtph264depay_1)
    self.player.add(self.h264parse_1)
    self.player.add(self.decodebin_1)
    self.player.add(self.videoconvert_1)
    self.player.add(self.autovideosink)

    ## Link elements
    self.tcpclientsrc_1.link(self.gdpdepay_1)
    self.gdpdepay_1.link(self.rtph264depay_1)
    self.rtph264depay_1.link(self.h264parse_1)
    self.h264parse_1.link(self.decodebin_1)
    self.decodebin_1.link(self.videoconvert_1)
    self.videoconvert_1.link(self.autovideosink)

## Create handles
def on_window_destroy(self, object, data=None):
    Gtk.main_quit()

def on_button1_clicked(self, object, data=None):
    w = self.entry_host_1.get_text().strip()
    self.start_stop(w)

def on_button2_clicked(self, object, data=None):
    a = ""

def on_button3_clicked(self, object, data=None):
    a = ""

def start_stop(self, w):
    if self.button1.get_label() == "Start":
        self.tcpiphost_1 = self.entry_host_1.get_text().strip()
        self.tcpport_1 = int(self.entry_port_1.get_text().strip())
        #print tcpiphost_1
        #print tcpport_1
        self.tcpclientsrc_1.set_property("host", self.tcpiphost_1)
        self.tcpclientsrc_1.set_property("port", self.tcpport_1)
        print self.tcpclientsrc_1.get_property("host")
        print self.tcpclientsrc_1.get_property("port")
        self.button1.set_label("Stop")
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    else:
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.button1.set_label("Start")

def on_message(self, bus, message):
    t = message.type
    if t == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        self.button1.set_label("Start")
    elif t == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        self.player.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        err, debug = message.parse_error()
        print "Error: %s" % err, debug
        self.button1.set_label("Start")

def on_sync_message(self, bus, message):
    if message.get_structure().get_name() == 'prepare-window-handle':
        imagesink = message.src
        imagesink.set_property("force-aspect-ratio", True)
        imagesink.set_window_handle(self.movie_window.get_property('window').get_xid())


GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)        
GTK_Main()
Gtk.main()
```

Note: Only here indents are incorrect. All are correct in script. :-)

Comment: I would recommend first making this work with gst-launch-1.0.. gst-launch is utility for testing/running pipelines from shell.. you can run this command: `gst-launch-1.0 tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.123 port=8888 ! gdpdepay ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink` .. personaly I have a feeling that you set properties like host/port too late .. you can try this way 1 create element, set properties, link..

Comment: Hey Otopolsky
I have run the pipeline with Gst-launcher to ensure that the pipeline was rolling and the stream was accessible. My goal was to create a G-streamer with Python and not just do the it the easyway. The Launcher have some tricks in the sleeve and another way is use launchparser. But i wanted to create and control the pipeline from a -> z.
So I worked further on with the script and i'm getting pretty close to my goal. Acutally i did consider to close this thread for 12 hours ago, as project was getting on track.